# Node serving same resources from all paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, react-router, browser-history

I'm using `React BrowserHistory` for navigation. I want the same files to be served from my Node server regardless of the URL path.

My server code:

```
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const hostname = 'localhost';

app.use(express.static('../public'));

app.get('*', (req, res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8007;
app.listen(port, ()=>{
  console.log('Production Express server running at localhost:' + port)
});
```

http://localhost:8007 => works fine

http://localhost:8007/help => works fine

http://localhost:8007/help/faq => Fails

I want all URLs to return the same resources, served from `../public`. However, it seems that the `express.static` doesn't work when the resource isn't requested from the root. So, for instance, when the browser asks for `<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>`, it thinks I want `../public/help/scripts/main.js`, whereas I actually want `../public/scripts/main.js/`. So, because express doesn't find such file, it moves on to the `app.get('*'...`, which returns the `../public/index.html` file when the script is requested.

So, the desired behavior is:

- return the same index.html for any path (with any number of sub-folders), and let React figure out what to show
- return the resources always relative to the path index.html is served from, not relative to the path in the URL

It works when I use absolute paths in my resource requests (I.E. `<script src="http://localhost:8007/scripts/main.js"></script>`), however writing it like that obviously isn't desirable, because it needs to be changed when it's hosted elsewhere.

What should I do?

Comment: That's what happens when you have relative URL's asking for scripts like that, regardless of the server, just change it to `<script src="/scripts/main.js">`

Comment: @adeneo I can't believe simply adding that slash in front of it solved it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use that condition for your routing:

```
app.get('*/**', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
});
```

It's work find for me.

Be carefull with this method, your browser will reload the entire page for each call to a route.